# Record is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have some store, which is formed data. On panel, it looks how "fieldName" and text field (in depension from invoked form).

For example, on one form is displayed "name document" and field, on another: date of selling and date field. Data is formed dynamically.

Here is store:

```
someStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: objectUrlAddress,
        baseParams: {
            'objectID' : objectID
        },
        root: 'Fields',
        fields: [
            {name: 'Hint'},
            {name:'Type', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Value'},
            {name: 'Index', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'IsRequired', type:'bool'},
            {name: 'Identifier'},
            {name: 'EnumList'},
            {name: 'Directory'},
            {name: 'Data'}
        ]});
```

Here's grid

```
var templateGrids = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        id: 'tableId',
        height:300,
        width: '100%',
        clicksToEdit:1,
        frame: true,
        store: tableTempStore,
        columns: 
        [{header: 'Объект', width:200, dataIndex: 'Hint'},
        {header: 'Значение', 
        dataIndex: 'Value', 
        width:300, 
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield'
        },
        getCellEditor: function(record) {
                var xtype = null,
                    args = {
                    fieldLabel: record.get('Hint'),
                    allowBlank: !record.get('IsRequired'),
                    value: record.get('Data'),
                    disabled: false
                };
                switch ('Type') {
                    case 0: // int
                        xtype = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        args.allowDecimals = false;
                    break;
                    case 1: // decimal
                        xtype = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        args.allowDecimals = true;
                    break;
                    case 2: // text
                        xtype = new Ext.form.TextField();
                    break;
                    case 3: // date
                        xtype = new Ext.form.DateField();
                        args.emptyText = 'дд.мм.гггг чч:мм';
                        args.format = 'd.m.y H:i';
                    break;
                    case 4: // enum
                    break;
                    case 5: // sql
                        var dataValues = Ext.util.JSON.decode(record.get('EnumList'));
                        var dataArray = Object.keys(dataValues).map(function(k) { return [k, dataValues[k]] });

                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox ';
                        args.store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                            fields: [
                                {name: 'myId', type: 'string'},
                                {name: 'displayText'}
                            ],
                            data: dataArray
                        });
                    break;
                    }
                        return new Ext.grid.CellEditor ({
                        field: Ext.create(xtype, args)
                        });
                }        
          }]
        });
```

Type of cell may be displayed in a grid in dependence from value of 'Type'.

For example if Type == 2, editor of column must be textvalue and etc. But my listener is not working and type is not changing. Besides, i get error "record.get is not a function".

Please help me to understand what wrong am I doing?

Comment: What you mean? This is my code.

Comment: Oh, this code from my project. I have a file with a set of properties and fields. First, i have been used form, where dynamacly displayed fields and properties. But listener with swich and cases were been in store listener. And for EditorGrid i have been used listener in grid. But it's show error "records in not a function"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53228523/8778804